# What might cause this background "fade" in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Anybody have any idea what might cause this in IE8? The background is meant to be a solid blue, but as you can see it's not. This is not on my machine and I've been unable to reproduce it, but one of my clients is getting it:

[image: Fade]

More details:  The background is using a png (which it doesn't strictly need to as it's a solid colour, but it's a legacy app so you know how that goes)

Also he says he is getting it on 2 machines in IE8. But all works fine on his end with chrome and firefox. I also have tried it in IE8, firefox, safari and chrome and they all work fine.

Comment: Just a thought bu have you ever had an image like this in your css? If so perhaps its caused by cached css or image?

Comment: yeah, that was my initial thought, but I got the user to delete his cache, etc and it's still doing it.  Also, that background has never had a gradient, so a bit stumped here. I'll add a couple more details

Comment: Some designer didn't like your solid colors and thought to do you a favor and change it? :D

Comment: heh, yeah, can't say I like it much either. But our client does so even when we've tried to update the look and feel he prefers the existing look. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this. I was using a semi-transparent 1x1 pixel image to overlay some text on a photo and IE8 "created" a fade in the background like your example.

The solution was simply to make the background 2x2 pixels and it works fine.

Hope this helps.